# How to know if windows update is waitng for installation

Tags: c#, windows-update

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way of detecting if Windows has Windows Updates ready to download/install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121585/best-way-of-detecting-if-windows-has-windows-updates-ready-to-download-install)

I am using C# .net 3.5.

How can I know if there are updates ready to be installed in Windows Update?

On windows 8, when Windows Update is waiting to install updates, the sleep option is disabled.

Instead of the regular 3 options: **1.** Sleep **2.** Restart **3.** Shutdown, there are only 2 options: **1.** Restart and update **2.** Shutdown and update. I need to identify this state and notify the user that the machine cannot move to sleep mode becuase updates are waiting to be installed.

Can I do it using WUAPILib?

Thanks

Comment: This is not exactlly the same question. I need to know if there are updates that require reboot that are waiting to be installed.

Answer (score 4):

You can use WUApiLib (Com lib) for this:

```
var updateSession = new UpdateSession();
var updateSearcher = updateSession.CreateUpdateSearcher();
updateSearcher.Online = false; //set to true if you want to search online
try
{
    var searchResult = updateSearcher.Search("IsInstalled=0 And IsHidden=0");
    if (searchResult.Updates.Count > 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("There are updates available for installation");
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message,"Error");
}
```

Click [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386515%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) if you want to know more.

Comment: Thanks! but this method returns true even if windows update is not waiting for the user to install the updates. I need to identify the state ehere windows update had downloaded updates and is waiting for the user to reboot the computer and install them.

Comment: @user844541 your question is clearer now. I don't know about Windows 8 but in Windows 7 WUA creates a reg key here `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update\RebootRequired` the adds a `DWORD` value of `1` to each update that requires a reboot (and in your case probably disables the sleep mode). note that these values will get removed after a reboot.

Comment: Is there also a wat to know if windows update is currently running? I don't want to reboot the computer when windows updata is running. I tried check if Wuauclt or TrustedInstaller are running, but apparently they are running even when windows update is not running.

Comment: @user844541 no idea. but you should post that as a new question since it's a different issue than the one you're having, and it'll make it easier to find for those trying to solve the same problem as you.