# How to know if windows has pending security updates from cmd or python?

Tags: python, windows

I need to know if windows has pending security updates from cmd or python.

I found an form to do this from cmd:

-First: I execute `>> C:\Windows\system32\wuauclt.exe /detectnow`

-After that: `>> Read the %systemroot%\WindowsUpdate.log` file information.

But I think must be another easy form to do this.

I found to that for C# exist an library named [WUApiLib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911218/how-to-know-if-windows-update-is-waitng-for-installation), this exist for python or something by style?

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly use Powershell for this sort of thing:

- https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/0dbfc125-b855-4058-87ec-930268f03285
- https://serverfault.com/questions/135191/shorcut-to-list-pending-updates-in-microsoft-windows

I can't find any direct way to access WSUS information. You might be able to get to them using PyWin32 or ctypes, but I was unable to find any examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command line tool Wuinstall (http://www.wuinstall.com) just like this:
wuinstall /search
lists all pending updates, with the /xmlout option you can save the whole list to an xml for further processing